# Using a list to select function to execute

Tags: r

I am trying to create a list with strings that depending on the value of a variable executes different functions.

This would be the code at this moment:

```
### Functions to be executed
execute_spain <- function(){

  print(paste0("execute spanish functions " ))
}
execute_portugal <- function(){

  print(paste0("execute portugal functions" ))
}
```

Then there would be a main where user would select a country

```
available_countries <- c("SPAIN","PORTUGAL","CHILE","BRAZIL")
country <- "SPAIN"

if(country %in% available_countries){
  print("available")
  if(country =="SPAIN"){
    ejecutar_spain()
  }else if (country =="PORTUGAL"){
    execute_portuguese_functions()
  }
}else{
  print("Error: country selected does not exist ")
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
available_countries <- c("SPAIN","PORTUGAL","CHILE","BRAZIL")
country <- "SPAIN"
function_to_execute <- c()
function_to_execute["SPAIN"] <- execute_spain()
function_to_execute["PORTUGAL"] <- execute_portugal()

if(country %in% available_countries){
  print("available")
  function_to_execute[country]
}else{
  print("Error: country selected does not exist ")
}
```

Am I bound to use an if with all the options available to select the function to execute?

Comment: Do you have only one function to execute for each country or there are multiple functions ?

Comment: I would implement a set of different functions for each country but I thought it would be easier to just make a call to a single function

Answer (score 2):

You could use a named vector

```
functions <- c(
   SPAIN = function(){print(paste0("execute spanish functions " ))},
   PORTUGAL = function(){print(paste0("execute portugal functions" ))}
)
```

and use it via

```
functions[["SPAIN"]]()
```

to check if the input is valid you can use

```
country <- "SPAIN"
hasName(functions, country)
```

### Edit

In more detail:

```
execute_spain <- function(){
  print(paste0("execute spanish functions " ))
}
execute_portugal <- function(){
  print(paste0("execute portugal functions" ))
}

functions <- c(
   SPAIN = execute_spain,
   PORTUGAL = execute_portugal
)

country <- "SPAIN"

if(hasName(functions, country){
  print("available")
  functions[[country]]()
}else{
  print("Error: country selected does not exist ")
}
```

Comment: I would like to keep functions declarations in another file since there would be many lines by function. In the example is just a print but depending on the country there would be different functions to execute. Thay take several hours to execute functions for each country

Comment: I edited the answer to go in a little more detail. In short: you can define the functions wherever you like and then just reference to them in the named vector